# How to handle the stop event when dragging with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

I have this plugin that handles dragging the mouse (not the content) and in the start drag handler I'm creating another element triggering a drag and stopping the parents but it's not working (the parent is still calling the dragHandler):
**(The reason for this is so I can be able to zoom/pan on mouse dragging.)**
**start** is called on mousedown, which also registers listeners for mousemove, etc.
**end** is called on mouseup, which also removes the listeners.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/62XZU/7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/62XZU/7/)

```
<svg></svg>
```

Plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ondrag = function(opt) {
        //console.log("set drag");
        var obj = this;
        opt = $.extend({start:null,drag:null,end:null,leave:null,dropElement:document}, opt);
        this.data('ondrag',opt);

        opt.dragHandler = function(e){ if (opt.drag) opt.drag.call(obj); e.stopPropagation(); };
        opt.leaveHandler = function(e){ if (opt.leave) opt.leave.call(obj); e.stopPropagation(); };
        opt.startHandler = function(e){
            if (opt.start) opt.start.call(obj); 
            $(document).on("mousemove",opt.dragHandler); 
            $(document.body).on("mouseleave",opt.leaveHandler); 
            $(document).on("mouseup",opt.endHandler); e.stopPropagation(); };
        opt.endHandler = function(e){ 
            if (opt.end) opt.end.call(obj); 
            $(document).off("mousemove",opt.dragHandler); 
            $(document.body).off("mouseleave",opt.leaveHandler); 
            $(document).off("mouseup",opt.endHandler); e.stopPropagation(); };
        this.on("mousedown",opt.startHandler);
        opt.stopdrag = function(){ //this should remove the svg listeners to stop dragging
            console.log("stop dragging", opt.drag);
            if (opt.end) opt.end.call(obj);
            $(document).off("mousemove",opt.dragHandler);
            $(document.body).off("mouseleave",opt.leaveHandler);
            $(document).off("mouseup",opt.endHandler);
        };

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Implementation:

```
$('svg').ondrag({
    start: function(){
        if (event.which==1) {//pan on left click
        } else { //create new element with drag and svg stop dragging
            console.log("started dragging on svg");
            $(document).trigger("mouseup"); //not working (svg is still dragging)
            this.data('ondrag').stopdrag(); //not working
            $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle'))
                .attr({r:50,fill:"lightgray",cx:"50%",cy:"50%"})
                .ondrag({
                    start:function(){ console.log("started dragging circle"); }, 
                    drag:function(){ console.log("dragging circle"); }
                }).appendTo(this).trigger("mousedown");
        }
    }, drag: function(){ console.log("dragging on svg"); }
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. What are you expecting it to do and what is it doing? The event is propagating, but you don't want it to? How is that manifesting and how would you prefer the system to act?

Comment: I want that in the moment that the circle is created, this circle starts dragging and the parent stops/cancel his dragging (that means the parent does not call dragHandler after this)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is the goal, but I think your browser is just dragging the image (svg) as browsers do when you click on an image. Did you try using preventDefault on out mousedown handlers.

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev All the drag handlers are working ok, I just can't remove the listeners from the svg node out of mouseup event and triggering mouseup manually is not working neither.

Comment: I just tried that, it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/62XZU/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you call your start function before you before your bind your mouse handlers, so your stop function has nothing to unbind.

http://jsfiddle.net/62XZU/6/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ondrag = function(opt) {
        //console.log("set drag");
        var obj = this;
        opt = $.extend({start:null,drag:null,end:null,leave:null,dropElement:document}, opt);
        this.data('ondrag',opt);

        opt.dragHandler = function(e){ if (opt.drag) opt.drag.call(obj); e.stopPropagation(); };
        opt.leaveHandler = function(e){ if (opt.leave) opt.leave.call(obj); e.stopPropagation(); };
        opt.startHandler = function(e){
            $(document).on("mousemove",opt.dragHandler); 
            $(document.body).on("mouseleave",opt.leaveHandler); 
            $(document).on("mouseup",opt.endHandler);
            if (opt.start) opt.start.call(obj); 
            e.stopPropagation();
        };
        opt.endHandler = function(e){ 
            opt.stopdrag();
            e.stopPropagation();
        };
        this.on("mousedown",opt.startHandler);
        opt.stopdrag = function(){
            console.log("stop dragging", opt.drag);
            $(document).off("mousemove",opt.dragHandler); 
            $(document.body).off("mouseleave",opt.leaveHandler); 
            $(document).off("mouseup",opt.endHandler);
            if (opt.end) opt.end.call(obj);
        };

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

All you need to do is move the callbacks to start/end below the on/off calls.

Comment: but the listeners are correctly registered, I mean they are working so why the stop function didn't unbind them?

Comment: Because the way you had it before the order of events was: 1. trigger mouseup, 1.1. call the start function, 1.1.1. call stop drag and unbind events, 1.1.2. crate new element and bind events to it, 1.2. bind events for parent element. So basically your start function was trying to unbind then, before the starHandler ever got the chance to bind them.